# How to redefine "\ " (that is "<backslash> <space>")?

Tags: spacing, macros

In (La)TeX, is there a way to redefine the command `\`  (that is "<backslash> <space>")?

I  have lots of texts where `\`  is used as non-breakable space after "." characters like in `Dr.\`  or `Mr.\`  and I want to make that space in the output just a bit shorter than the normal space.

Please note, I do *not* want to change the texts, but rather redefine the `\`  macro in the preamble. Is this possible?

Comment: The `\ ` macro inserts ordinary (breakable) space, *not* non-breakable space. For non-breakable space, you should use (and suitably modify, as necessary) the `~` symbol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would strongly recommend against this, but it can be done. The command `\`  is a primitive meaning 'a normal space' so shows up in various places, in particular the definition of `\nobreakspace`. Thus a 'safe' redefinition of `\`  must at least deal with that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\hardspace\ %
\DeclareRobustCommand*\nobreakspace{\leavevmode\nobreak\hardspace}
%\let\ ~
\begin{document}

Some text to show that this is now a non-breaking space in a demo:
Mr.\ Black.

\let\ ~

Some text to show that this is now a non-breaking space in a demo:
Mr.\ Black.

\end{document}
```

I've commented out `\let\ ~` in the preamble in the above so that the demo shows the effect of the change, but in a real case you'd apply it to everything. As pointed out by others, you *really* should use the correct mark-up to differentiate between a 'forced' normal space and a non-breaking space.

Comment: As the poster I have to explain what the reason for my question was: I write my papers in Markdown and convert them with [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) via LaTeX to pdf or to html. Markdown has basckslash-space as non-breakable space and I though that the same is in TeX, but of course not: So pandoc converts the Markdown-backslash-space into TeX-tilde, so if anything I redefine tilde in LaTeX as a little narrower space. Done that and it works great. But your answer is of course perfectly valid for the backslash-space redefinition.

Answer (score 1):

For example, starting from the definition of `~`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\hallospace{\penalty\@M \kern0.3em} % say, 0.3em
\let\oldspace=\ %
\let\ =\hallospace
\makeatother
```

(And remember to use `~` as an unbreakable space in the future).